# Can we save jpeg/png images in java collection?

Tags: java, collections, png, jpeg

I wanted to know can we save images with a jpeg or a png format in a Java Collection like Maps/HashMap/TreeMap/ArrayList etc...?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't that be possible?  What did you try, where did you get stuck?

Comment: i am having a rest webservice build up solely on Java Collections and it has an android client app which when required can take snaps but i dont know or not aware of how to save the captured image in Java Collection(s) ...

Comment: yes of course, instance your image by BufferedImage, and beware about the memory

Comment: bdw why was it downvoted ??

Comment: so just keep an instance of image if you have to doing some process on it, it is not good idea to keep images in memory, simply persist them in the hard disk

Comment: hmm...but WE CAN SAVE IT na..now it would be wise of you to show me some example or tutorial on that (if possible)..

Comment: You probably deserve to be downloaded for blatant laziness, but ok... go [here (The Java2D tutorial @ oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

Comment: @fvu i was unable to find it when i googled it !!
http://bit.ly/14twK5d

Comment: @AltairRules that's because your search phrase is way too generic and low on interesting keywords.  Try `java jpeg png object` and you'll get several useful hits.  Also, at least going through eg the Oracle tutorial set to get an idea of what functionality exists would be a good idea, you really cannot google a program together, there's stuff you should at least know exists.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments, I think that you may have the wrong view of what files actually are. Files are sequences of bits. That's it. They are not objects in Java or anything.

That being said, we can *make* an object out of an image file. This can be done with the [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new File("path/to/file"); //as many times as you need

        //at this point, you have all of your "images" in an ArrayList!
    }
}
```

Now notice that Java has absolutely no idea that these are images. In fact, the object really only represents the path to the file. It is not a good idea to store these images in memory. Store them on disk, and access them when you need them.